# How to a add timestamp to an online generated pdf document using PHP (Zend_PDF)

Tags: php, pdf, timestamp, signature, zend-pdf

I am generating online a PDF document using PHP and Zend_PDF.
How can I timestamp this documents and add a digital signature?
It would be okay to use another library for timestamping, as well. Currently I just found commercial products!

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework does not support the creation of digital certificates for PDF files. See the following link for more information, along with a link to a free third party solution:

http://www.framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-10950